# VB.net VS2010: Dynamic object type that changes to match class name

Tags: vb.net, class, object, dynamic, types

I tried to search a bit before asking but I really had no idea what to search for on this one so here's what I'm looking for:

I need a way to declare an object in VB.net so that I can set it to the current class(using the class as the object type) but if the class name changes then the object type changes to match the new class name. Here's an example.

> Class UhhWhat
>
> > Dim L As List(Of UhhWhat)
> >
> > Sub add()
> >
> > > ```
> > >   L.Add(Me)
> > > ```
> >
> > End Sub
>
> End Class

So if this were my code and someone copied it to a new class with a different name say... "UhhNo" then I would want the "List(Of UhhWhat)" to change to "List(Of UhhNo)".

Does that make sense? I'm not really stuck on having the name for the object type, I just want something that will function like the List object's Of T but use the current class' type rather than a type supplied to a subroutine.
I would like this done when the code is written, not at runtime because I need intellisense to continue to function for the new type.

Lastly, I do know that simply using "List(Of Object)" would help my problem.. however this will not work for intellisense and I have heard that declaring an object as "object" type is slower than if you declared it as a specific type.

To sum it up what I'm looking for is a way to change the object type to whatever the programmer changes the class name to, automatically.

Thx a bunch :)

--EDIT--
I found the solution I was looking for in a rather simple place.. the VS rename function.. ahh another time when the answer was so simple.

Kudos to David W for their patience with me, thx a bunch David W!
I hope i didn't bug ya too much with my vague ideas :)
I appreciate the suggestions :)

Comment: If a developer takes your class and adds it to their own project, then renames the class, VS2010 will typically provide a small pop-up rename helper to change the references from the original name to the new name...is that what you're after?

Comment: @DavidW hmm.. would that work for when they need to change the list type of the imported code? Also I found something earlier about inherited classes, so if I decided to use that I wouldn't be able to use the "inherits" keyword. It's just a thought. Or I could combine both and simply exclude the parts that need to be dynamic from the inheritable class.

Comment: Well, its just a text search-and-replace helper, nothing more, so I wouldn't assume it would do anything too extravagant. I'm just not entirely clear on how you are trying to control the *name* of a class if another developer uses it...seems like there are all manner of inheritance and implementation features you could be using if other devs will be using your code...if you're concerned about changing types of the List, keep it generic, eg List<T> and make your class declaration generic such that implementors can specify whatever type they may need...

Comment: @davidw I'm not having luck with my searches because I'm not exactly sure how to explain my problem. Tell me if this makes sense though... I'm trying to refer to the current class as a type so I can set an object's type to the class, but I can't simply do it like "dim obj as ThisClass" because the code will be re-used in classes using different names for the class. Do you think I should just have all the code inherited and then just have them edit the type name to reflect what they name their class? Or is there a better way? The above code is what I have but "UhhWhat" would be the class name

Comment: The part I'm not getting is where you state "so I can set an object's type to the class." An object's type isn't something you can change or set arbitrarily. Every instance of UhhWhat is an UhhWhat. You can't decide, at runtime, to say "this instance of UhhWhat is now a FooBar." unless FooBar is part of UhhWhat's inheritance hierarchy. If you're defining common base functionality that other developers will leverage, you could define an abstract base class that provides some implementation, but requires developers to provide implementation-specific details in concrete classes.

Comment: @davidw Yes I know I guess I didn't explain very well... hm.. What I'm trying to do is make this so that the object type is set beforehand(when you're actually writing your program's code). Such as when you're using doubles but then decide you want to use singles instead, you just change your code to use "As single" instead of "As  double". This scenario though, the idea is to inherit the original code but change the types in the old code to reflect the change in the class name. if the class was "OldClass" and is now "NewClass", all "As OldClass" would become "NewClass" **when it is copied**

Comment: @davidw Example of this functionality would be when you use the "rename" in the solution explorer and it automatically renames the class name to what you changed the file name to. The only difference is that I'm trying to have it change the types for objects set to that class too. EDIT: oops... I tried what I just suggested and it fixed my problem ... how embarrassing.. well ty for your time, hopefully I didn't bug ya too much :)

Comment: Hmm....Sounds to me like you're looking for a more sophisticated code renaming/editing utility for VS2010 rather than a language feature. What is the difference between what you're wanting and performing a normal ol' global search and replace (project or solution level) of "oldClassName" to "newClassName" ?

Comment: @davidW Well I was really just looking for something to auto-rename the "As YourClass" whenever the class name was changed and preferably something that would work with the "inherits" keyword too. But yeah the solution I found? any object with the class as it's type will be automatically renamed when VS2010 renames the "YourClass.vb" file in solution explorer. Amazing how simple the solution was :O   Anywho how do I send you reputation for helping me?

Comment: I'll just post the rename as the solution and you can accept that, if that's ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Solution Explorer, when you rename a class file, Visual Studio will fix the corresponding class names accordingly.